# Cloud Storage Transfer "Failed"

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, transfer

I've tried repeatedly to use the Google Developers Console tools to Create a Transfer that works, but haven't had any luck. My source is in S3.

I tried with the "S3://" URL, but when trying to accept the transfer settings, I consistently get "source bucket doesn't exist". I test my URL by placing it in a browser, and I do get it to resolve, so I don't know what's up.

Even more puzzling is when I try using a text file of URLs. These URLs are all http:// strings, and each of them properly loads in a browser. I figured this would be even more straightforward as there are no permissions to be dealt with, really, since each file in the S3 bucket already has read permissions.

Instead, all I get in the Transfer history is "Failed", with no other information at all.

At first, I was greedy and included all my files. When I got nowhere with that, I cut it down to a single file. Still no go.

[Here](https://storage.googleapis.com/ebay-radio-files/test.txt) is  the text file.

Any clues, por favor?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your text file doesn't follow the specified format. You should add the header and size/MD5 of each file as described at https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/#urls

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this. I appreciate your response!